# Android XmlPullParser reset trouble

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I need to load xml, parse it and then reset parser to start document(without loading again). When i parse it for the first time - everything works good. But when i call setInput() to reset the parser and parse again - it does not work.

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
XmlPullParser xmlTag;
InputStream inputStream;

try {
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    xmlTag = factory.newPullParser();
    inputStream = MainSettings.getContext().getAssets().open("level1.xml");
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i("tag", "before parse first time");
this.loadXML();
Log.i("tag", "before parse second time");
this.loadXML();
Log.i("tag", "After parse second time");

.....................................

private void loadXML() {
    try {
        xmlTag.setInput(inputStream, null);
        int eventType = xmlTag.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            eventType = xmlTag.next();
            Log.i("tag", eventType + "   " + xmlTag.getName());
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In output i get:

```
before parse first time
2   data
4   null
2   item
4   null
3   item
4   null
3   data
1   null
before parse second time
1   null
After parse second time
```

So the second time parser does not work. And code passes without exceptions. Can anybody help, please? 
Here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <item>
        Text
    </item>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but for a record for future visitors:

The input stream should be re-initialized and then set as input to the parser. below code will work as expected in the question:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
XmlPullParser xmlTag;
InputStream inputStream;

try {
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    xmlTag = factory.newPullParser();

} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i("tag", "before parse first time");
this.loadXML();
Log.i("tag", "before parse second time");
this.loadXML();
Log.i("tag", "After parse second time");

.....................................

private void loadXML() {
    try {
        inputStream =  MainSettings.getContext().getAssets().open("level1.xml");
        xmlTag.setInput(inputStream, null);
        int eventType = xmlTag.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            eventType = xmlTag.next();
            Log.i("tag", eventType + "   " + xmlTag.getName());
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you just were setting the parser input source but not re-initializing the input stream.